# Named and unnamed people in Torah

Tags: names

Jacob went to Egypt with "his sons and grandsons, his daughters and granddaughters—all his offspring". [Gen. 46:7]  Many men's names follow, but only one woman's name: Serach, "sister of Asher's sons" [Gen. 46:17].  The Midrash tells us more about her and her righteous actions [Gen. Rabbah 94:9, Eccl. Rabbah 9:18:2].

It is tempting to conclude from this that the Torah only mentions or refers to significant people, not everybody.  Yet it has many lists of names that recur nowhere else in the Sources.  Did these people make significant contributions that were lost?  If not, why the apparent inconsistency?

Comment: Seems to usually list all men, and significant women.